# Select the main class of a Java project in VSC

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I developed a small Swing application in Java with VSC and it compiles perfectly, but when I generate the JAR and run it, it does not work as the main method of the application is not defined. I understand this is because in the Jar's `MANIFEST.MF` file, the class is not specified.

I knew how to choose it from NetBeans (in project settings), but I can't find how to do it from VSC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Main()` is needed in jar when running it, but when quoting the jar in other project, `main()` is optional. Please follow my steps and have a try.

1. Open **Command Palette** and choose **Java: Export Jar**, there will be a jar without `main()` generated in current project.
   [image]
2. In other projects, add the jar to referenced libraries, then use the function like `jarname.function()`:
   [image]

Make sure the method in jar is the type of `public` or it couldn't be called.